# Multiple collections in AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

AngularFire comes with a simple [chat example](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/gh-pages/examples/chat/app.js#L5):

```
angular.module('chat', ['firebase'])
  .controller('Chat', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'angularFireCollection',
    function($scope, $timeout, angularFireCollection) {
      var url = 'https://angularFire.firebaseio.com/chat';
      $scope.messages = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url).limit(50));
      $scope.username = 'Guest' + Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
      $scope.addMessage = function() {
        $scope.messages.add({from: $scope.username, content: $scope.message});
        $scope.message = "";
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('autoScroll', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elements, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("messages.length", function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          elements[0].scrollTop = elements[0].scrollHeight
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

How could you modify the collection to store multiple collections?

For example, it is currently a collection of messages. But say we want to extend it to contain a collection of messages, and a collection of usernames?

I can do this directly by manually modifying the database, but I can't seem to get the data back out so I think I'm doing something completely wrong here:

```
$scope.data = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url));
$scope.messages = data.getByName('messages');  // undefined
$scope.users = data.getByName('users');        // undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to wait for angularFireCollection to initialize ('download' your data from the Firebase servers) before trying to get data out of it.

```
$scope.data = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url), onInit);
function onInit() {
  $scope.messages = data.getByName('messages');
  $scope.users = data.getByName('users');
}
```

However, it seems no $digest is triggered when the onInit callback is fired.  I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/170).  For now you can wrap onInit's contents in a $timeout.

Comment: That should do it : )